# Drupal theming stop using panels for mobile site

Tags: php, drupal, themes

I'm working on a Drupal mobile site which is powered by the Mobile module. The non-mobile theme uses panels, and the mobile theme does not. I need to turn off panels for the mobile theme as the panels appear and ruin its layout. How can I do this, or is there a better way to achieve a separate mobile site in general? We're running Drupal 6.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Okay, and how would I go about setting that up? Don't multiple drupal sites with the same DB inherit panel settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to do some hacking in the [template_preprocess_page()](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/template_preprocess_page/6) function.  I've never tried to do what you're doing, as I don't use the panels module.

What kind of stuff does the panels module put into your content?  Maybe you can do it with CSS?

Hope this helps.

Comment: I decided to go with multisite. Thanks anyway for the help!